# How do I find the position of a word in a list using a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know this question was asked many times on here, but could not find an adequate answer.

I need to find the position of the words in a list, when I run my code it gives me `None`

Here is the code:

```
words = ['Banana', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Peach', 'Grapefruit', 'St', 'Apple']

def get_position(words, type_word):
    for idx, value in enumerate(words):
        if value in words == type_word:
            return idx
        

positions = get_position(words, 'Apple')
print(positions)
```

Preferred Output:

```
[2, 3, 8]
```

Comment: `if value in words == type_word` is the wrong way to do it.  You're already iterating over `words`, so you _know_ value is in the list.  Just use `if value == type_word`.

Comment: use ```if value in words == type_word``` check my answer

Answer (score 0):

if you use `return` then function will return the value you want to give back. same is happening here in your code, it is returning the first matched value and not checking further.

either use `yield` or a temporay list where you saved match result and then return back

```
def get_position(words, type_word):
    for idx, value in enumerate(words):
        if value == type_word:
            yield idx
```

or

```
def get_position(words, type_word):
    matched = []
    for idx, value in enumerate(words):
        if value == type_word:
            matched.append(idx)
    return matched
```

Comment: `if value in words == type_word` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare an empty list and append the index to the list when you find a match.
Then after the loop, you have to return the list.
The code will be something like this:

```
words = ['Banana', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Peach', 'Grapefruit', 'St', 'Apple']

def get_position(words, type_word):
    ret = []
    for idx, value in enumerate(words):
        if value in words == type_word:
            ret.append(idx)
    return ret
        

positions = get_position(words, 'Apple')
print(positions)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
outlist = []
def get_position(words, type_word):
    for idx, value in enumerate(words):
        if value == type_word:
            outlist.append(idx)
    return outlist
```

Comment: The break after `return` is unreachable; moreover, this won't return a list.

Comment: @augurar sorry that was draft got submitted, updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension.

Use:

```
def get_position(words, type_word):
    return [idx for idx, w in enumerate(words) if w == type_word]
```

Output:

```
>>> get_position(words, "Apple")
[2, 3, 8]
```

Comment: How do I just return a single value and put that code into the function? (In the format of my question)?

Comment: You want a list as output. What do you mean by returning a single value?

Comment: Replace `if value in words == type_word` with `if value == type_word`.  Your function will now return the index corresponding to the first occurrence of `type_word` in `words`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of solving this issue:

```py
words = ['Banana', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Peach', 'Grapefruit', 'St', 'Apple']


def get_indexes(lst_from):
    lst = []
    for i in range(len(lst_from)):
        index = lst_from[i:].index('Apple') + i
        if index not in lst:
            lst.append(index)
    
    return lst
```